Introducing typified addresses to avoid sending funds to void
I have sent SOL to a contract address by mistake thinking that I was buying the token, that caused me to loss all the SOL.
After few days of investigation I end up to know that this did happen to many people already, why nobody does nothing about it?
If this is how blockchain/solana works by default, but if this is causing an issue to everyone, since nobody benefits from these operations to these addresses, why not addressing this issue seriously and fix it at the fundamental level ?
(not sure if is possible or not, since I am not a blockchain developer expert, but addresses should be typified (wallet and contract types) and for instance addresses of type contract will not allow this operations of sending funds!
A simple solution such this one will be beneficial to everyone right ?
(I am posting this here, but perhaps any of you can take it to the right people, if this cannot be solved at solana level)
Like it is right now is like driving down a country road for the first time, on a dim night filled with dense fog. Suddenly, the road ends in a precipice. Due to the dense fog, it was almost impossible to see the road signs, and you just fall off...
